# Send request from HTTPS to HTTP and get response

Tags: jquery, https, httpresponse

I have a site that uses HTTPS connection. It runs a PHP script for uploading video to a HTTP  server, and on successful upload the server returns a key as response. The request can be done successfully but it is not getting any response due to protocol mismatch. The request and response everything is done through AJAX.

After I upload the video Google Chrome console shows error:

```
The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from http://remote-server.com
[blocked] The page at https://www.my-site.com/
```

I have tried using `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')` but its not working.

I have also tried making request using 'https://' but Chrome console says `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL data:text/html,chromewebdata from frame with URL https://www.my-site.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

How can I send request from HTTPS connection to HTTP and get response.

Comment: You can't. Browsers prevents this by default as otherwise it would be insecure to allow it. The remote server must have a valid SSL certificate and use HTTPS. Or else, serve up your uploader on a non-SSL connection.

Comment: Could you please make yourself clear here "serve up your uploader on a non-SSL connection"

Comment: Your site is served in HTTPS. The resource you want to access is HTTP only. If you want to access it, you must serve your site also in HTTP and not HTTPS. So perhaps on the page where you upload your video, serve that page using HTTP and not HTTPS.